# Access variable defined in one callback from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Without creating a variable in a more global space (or using `.data()`), is it possible to access a variable in one callback (i.e. `open`) which is defined in another (i.e. `create`)?  I know the following will not work, but wonder if my variable can be access through the `event` or `ui` objects.

```
//var myVariable; //Without defining myVariable here or using data()
var dialog=$('#dialog').dialog({
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        var myVariable=123;
    },
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(event, ui);
        console.log(myVariable); //undefined
    }
});
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.  As you suspect, you'll need to define the variable in a scope that's accessible to both functions, or use some other storage mechanism, such as `data` like you suggested.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen.  I thought so, but wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: actually, there **may be** a (hacky?) way - but it really depends on how things are called!

Comment: @JaromandaX  Curious.  Feel free to add it so I can't close this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the downside is, that `this` wont be what it usually would be in create and open

```
var dialog=$('#dialog').dialog({
    myVariable: 0,
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        this.myVariable=123;
    }.bind(this),
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(event, ui);
        console.log(this.myVariable); //undefined
    }.bind(this)
});
```

// not sure if the following is the best way to do the closure as suggested in the comments

```
var dialog=$('#dialog').dialog(
    (function() {
        var myVariable;
        return {
            create: function( event, ui ) {
                myVariable=123;
            },
            open: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log(event, ui);
                console.log(this.myVariable); //undefined
            }
        };
    }())
);
```

Comment: ew, but +1 :)  Seriously though @user1032531 - use a closure around the whole lot!

Comment: yep, closure is the way to go for sure

Comment: Yes, I suppose this answers the question.  Not that I will do it, however :)

Comment: I've added an alternate